# Como eu faço para pegar o conteúdo de um texto que esta no link (URL) e carregá-lo no TextView?

Tags: java, android

Eu preciso de uma forma de carregar através de uma URL um texto que nela está.
O texto é grande, e desta forma a aplicação ficaria mais leve. Quero setar o texto que for baixado deste link em um `TextView`.

Comment: Tem de explicar melhor o que pretende. O que que dizer com "(...) carregar através de uma URL um texto (...)"? É o conteúdo html duma página? É o json/xml retornado?

Comment: Quero setar o texto do link no textview, mas não o link.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_HQ8JP4ovcIbVcxQ3RvcDFtWHc  esse texto na aplicação exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Para baixar o texto, tente isso:

```java
public static String download(String url) throws IOException {
    try {
        return download(new URL(url));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}

public static String download(URL url) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baixado = new ByteArrayOutputStream(20480);
    try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
        int t;
        while ((t = is.read()) != -1) {
            baixado.write(t);
        }
        return baixado.toString();
    }
}

private static String FURIA_DE_TITANS_URL = "https://example.com/furiadetitans";
```

Depois, você só tem que fazer isso:

```java
seuTextView.setText(download(FURIA_DE_TITANS_URL));
```

Entretanto, não sei se essa é a melhor ideia para você. A menos que a quantidade de textos seja muito grande ou mude com muita frequência, consumir conexão a internet com isso não me parece ser uma boa ideia, e seria mais fácil se os textos estivessem dentro do seu aplicativo mesmo.

Comment: Mas não seria um download e sim um carregamento simples, tipo de uma imagem que é carregada por uma conexão url. assim que a aplicação é fechada o texto não existe mais e quando for reaberta o texto e novamente carregado assim com os demais.

Comment: @Moysés Não entendi sua colocação. Se o programa baixa alguma coisa da internet, mesmo que seja durante o seu carregamento, o nome desta ação é download.

Comment: Sim mas o arquivo do texto não é para ser armazenado no dispositivo, e sim só visualizado assim como nos navegadores.

Comment: @Moysés Editei a resposta. É isso que você quer?

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho certeza se é possível fazer isso com um arquivo de texto diretamente do Google Drive, porque na verdade quando você clica no link do comentário referente ao seu `.txt`, ele abre não somente um texto, mas um gerenciador de visualização de textos.

Mas respondendo sua pergunta, tem como você listar dados de um .txt usando um [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Então criei um arquivo `.txt` no qual é possível vê-lo como texto quando é aberto pelo *browser* para exemplificar.

Exemplo básico de uso do `AsyncTask`:

```
 new AsyncTask<Void,String,String>(){
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return toString();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String results){
        }
    }.execute();
```

Lendo arquivo da URL:

```
URL url = new URL(url_desejada);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String str;
while ((str = in .readLine()) != null) {

} in.close();
```

Código completo:

```
new AsyncTask < Void, String, String > () {

    // variavel criada para receber o texto da url
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void...params) {
        try {
            // Cria uma URL com o arquivo desejado
            URL url = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cleidimarviana/SOpt/master/TEXT/loremipsum.txt");

            // Ler o texto retornado pelo servidor
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String str;
            while ((str = in .readLine()) != null) {
                // str se refere a linha do texto retornado pelo servido
                // no entanto o usso do append eh para concatenar todas as linas
                text.append(str);
            } in .close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // aqui pode ser inserido uma alerta referente a comunicao
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
        // result é a resposta recebida pelo doInBackGround()
        // entao a linha abaixo define o textview com o resultado esperado
        textview.setText(results);
    }
}.execute();
```

Para deixar registrado, criei um arquivo com o nome [GetTextFileByURL](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/SOpt/blob/master/Android/GetTextFileByURL.java) no Github.